# Django - JupyterHub - OAuth2 - Jupyter Notebook Interaction

Tags: django, authentication, oauth, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have a rather complex requirement. Here is what I hope to achieve.

- A Django backend that shall host all kinds of information about the user of a service.
- User will log into Django backend and can send some instructions or query to the service.
  OR
- The user can access a Jupyter notebook from within the Django app and use an API to communicate the query to the service. This might be a preferred mode of accessing the service since the results are something that need further analysis using Python.
- Whether it is a query sent using a form within the Django service OR whether query is sent using a Python API from within a notebook, it is sent to the same web URL/endpoint so that the query can be logged etc.
- This URL is protected by authentication.

Now, what I have managed to do so far is the following:

- Configure Django to provide OAuth based authentication.
- Configure JupyterHub to communicate with Django and start a user specific notebook server.
- I have even figured out how to use Jupyter Notebook Extensions to pre-populate any new notebook with the relevant code and comments that will help the user use our API.

Now, our API could have a `.query()` method which I could call like `API.query('the query')`. Then there will be a whole lot of other methods to track the progress of the query etc. Now, I was thinking of using the 'requests' library to send a POST to the endpoint within Django in-charge of receiving the query and submitting to a task queue. But since this Django endpoint is login protected, I need the headers of this request to be populated with an OAuth access token.

Here is the actual question - how

- within a notebook
- running on a notebook server
- authenticated by JupyterHub via OAuth through Django
- can I get the 'access token'
- so that I can attach it to all request headers
- which communicate with protected endpoints in my Django application.

My research efforts so far

- The Jupyterhub REST API (https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/rest.html) - does not seem to provide straightforward endpoints which can help me fetch the access tokens.
- The Jupyterhub API (https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/) - I don't come from a solid Tornado background to be able to understand this. I think the answer lies here. But I am not sure.
- During a discussion on Github issues, I came across this (https://github.com/wildtreetech/ohjh/tree/master/images/refresher). But I'm not sure if this will truly satisfy my requirements. A comment on a) if this is what I need and b) can I use it as is for my use case as is or c) after modifications would be great.

If there is a completely different approach that can help meet these requirements, I would be open to this as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd update that I was able to solve the problem in the following way:

- Designed my Django backend to generate a token file with appropriate ownership and deposit it inside the user directory.
- Designed my Python "client package" to use this token to authenticate itself.
- And added a middleware to recognize clients such as above based on the token.

I'm currently working on taking all these things and gluing them together in a `docker-compose` file. Trying to solve the issue where DockerSpawner creates Jupyter containers that unfortunately can't access the outside world and hence the Django based web app.

Referencing the related Stackoverflow question here: [No outside network access for Jupyter Notebook container spawned by JupyterHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59871431/no-outside-network-access-for-jupyter-notebook-container-spawned-by-jupyterhub)

A shout out to all the wonderful people involved in this and related projects. The discussions, the documents etc. have been important in figuring out many things.